# Cannot implicitly convert type with extension method

Tags: c#, casting

I have a extension method for an enum

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetFlags<T>(this T value) where T : struct
    {
        CheckIsEnum<T>(true);
        foreach (T flag in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>())
        {
            if (value.IsFlagSet(flag))
                yield return flag;
        }
    }
```

I try to get the result like this:

```
Zone_Status_ZoneConditionFlagEnum flags = (Zone_Status_ZoneConditionFlagEnum)flagsRaw;

List<Zone_Status_ZoneConditionFlagEnum> ZoneConditionFlags_List = (List<Zone_Status_ZoneConditionFlagEnum>)flags.GetFlags();
```

But I get

```
NX584(NX584Test)->Error parsing message: Cannot implicitly convert type [Digicom.NX584Engine.Messages.Zone_Status_ZoneConditionFlagEnum] to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Digicom.NX584Engine.Messages.Zone_Status_ZoneConditionFlagEnum].
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear to me why you're getting *that* error - but you can't cast the result of `GetFlags<T>` to a `List<T>`, because it doesn't return a `List<T>`. The simplest fix would be:

```
var ZoneConditionFlags_List = flags.GetFlags().ToList();
```

If *that* doesn't work, please give the new error message.

Alternatively, you could change `GetFlags` so it actually returned a `List<T>` rather than using an iterator block.

Answer (score 1):

The first issue here is that a sequence is different to a list; if you need a list, either *return* a list, or add `.ToList()` after `GetFlags()`, i.e.

```
var ZoneConditionFlags_List = flags.GetFlags().ToList();
```

However, the bigger problem is that you can't use that `IsFlagSet` in that generic context; that method is not defined for an arbitrary `T : struct`.

Personally, I think you'd be better just to treat it as a `[Flags]` enum throughout; I assume you have existing code that wants a list rather than a single value?

Answer (score 0):

`GetFlags` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, not a `List<T>`, you cannot *cast* here.

You should, however, be able to construct a list from the results:

```
List<Zone_Status_ZoneConditionFlagEnum> ZoneConditionFlags_List = flags.GetFlags().ToList();
```

However, the error does not match the code here exactly, it should complain about an IEnumerable not be able to be cast, but instead it says the enum type. Are you sure this is the right code?